# Why Entity Framework creates multiple processes in sys.sysprocesses when run one single query?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

While running one single (but complicated) query using Entity Framework, I saw that there are multiples processes that have been created with `program_name` = `EntityFramework` by using this query:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName,
        hostname, *
FROM    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE   dbid > 0
        and program_name = 'EntityFramework'
```

Are all of these processes are individual connections that are opened by EF? What does `process` mean by the way?

Although all these processes will disappear as soon as the query finishes, if they are indeed individual connection, my concern is about the performance of the query.

Here are a sample data from running the query above:

```
spid   kpid   cmd              net_library  loginame    sql_handle                                 stmt_start  stmt_end    request_id
------ ------ ---------------- ------------ ----------- ------------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
54     4400   SELECT           TCP/IP       api-admin   0x01000A00C04E6A1F905F5AB19000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     9792   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     5036   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     9644   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     7796   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     5512   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     8660   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     9376   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     9108   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     7464   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     8644   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
54     4640   SELECT           TCP/IP                   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 442         4820        2
```

I'm thinking that they are not really a connection, but just the extra work that MSSQL generated by itself, because they share the same `spid`, only `kpid` is different. And only 1 of them have `loginame`.

Checking IntelliTrace also shows only one call of ADO.NET. Does this guarantee only one connect/request is sent to the DB?

Comment: `sysprocesses` is an old-style view. From SQL Server 2005 onwards it's been replaced with three new views: `dm_exec_connections`, `dm_exec_sessions` and `dm_exec_requests`. This avoids the confusing "process" terminology, and will also allow you to see that only one connection is in use.

Comment: Can you explain what is `connections`, `sessions`, or `requests`? Or do you know where can I lookup the definition for those terminologies?

Comment: [Tasks, Workers, Threads, Scheduler, Sessions, Connections, Requests – what does it all mean?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlmeditation/2012/12/13/tasks-workers-threads-scheduler-sessions-connections-requests-what-does-it-all-mean/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They represent parallelism within the query execution.

SQL Server's optimizer can decide that some parts of the query will benefit from parallelism<sup>1</sup> and so will allow the query to use more than one "process". These are not OS processes but are more akin to threads, but process is the term used within SQL Server.

---

<sup>1</sup>Under the not unreasonable assumption that the server will be working with multiple connections, there's no real means to *force* the server to employ parallelism for your query, only to *allow* it to choose to do so. The [`MAXDOP` hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) can be applied to *limit* parallelism if it turns out that high parallelism is actually harmful for your specific query.

Comment: So, if I want to count the number of connections, I'd only count the number of distinct `spid` right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sys.sysprocesses to see what is running, use sys.dm_exec_requests:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests r
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) q
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) p
```

The above query includes the SQL text and the execution plan.